# Is there any way to open a new connection using ssl without another handshake?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm working on designing a server, in which the protocol allows for the client to open additional physical connections to the server which operate in the context of a single logical connection.

One thought I had was that, if we're using ssl, we'll need to do another ssl handshake for the new connection. It seems to me that it should be possible to send some secret to the client over the original, secure connection that would allow the new connection to be securely established without a handshake (similarly to what I've read about ssl session reuse).

Is this actually possible?

Answer (score 1):

SSL already does this. Provided both ends support it, there is a feature called 'session resumption' which allows a new connection via an existing SSL session, via a much abbreviated handshake, without the certificate exchange and negotiation of shared secrets.

Comment: I want to go from n connections (from the same client) to n+1. Not really 'resuming' a session

Comment: There's a lot of talk surrounding resumption and TLS Fast Start in TLS 1.3. It will be interesting to see if they provide something secure, or skimp on security and start consuming data before its been authenticated.

Comment: Bwmat - You did say you wanted to *"open a new connection using ssl without another handshake?"* - Don't make requirements a moving target  :)

Comment: @Bwmat That is exactly what 'resuming' a session means.

Comment: @jww Surely it is inconceivable that they won't 'provide something secure'?

Comment: @jww - the word 'new' may be confusing in that context, but I don't see how I've contradicted myself?

Comment: @Bwmat If what you want isn't met by session resumption, you have made your requirements a moving target. You need to explain this, not just argue about whether 'new' is 'confusing'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by reusing SSL Session. You can do this by using `PEM_write_bio_SSL_SESSION` and `PEM_read_bio_SSL_SESSION` and then adding it to SSL Context.

Keep in mind you only need to do this in client mode, server mode does this automatically for you.